# SVG displays only numbers but not text from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, svg, jspdf

I can display the text/numbers in pdf document created from the SVG element but, there's a case where I have to display the data from the PHP script and it display only the numbers in the pdf but not the text.

The below is the general code from my script

https://codepen.io/WhoAmIAmWho/pen/bQQLXa

If I replace the text "Test Case for 1" with

```
'+<?PHP echo $test;?> +' 

//If $test contains numbers (1,2,3,4....) It is displaying in pdf

//If $test contains text(A,B,C,D....) It is not displaying the pdf and it is truncating
```

What might be the reason and how can I display the text?

Comment: The characters used for the text might not be included with the font.

Comment: How do you create the PDF from SVG?

Comment: What do you mean from your first comment? Could you please elaborate it. I create the pdf using Highcharts default export

Comment: What font do you use in the PDF?

Comment: It prints the normal text from my code but, it isn't showing only if the text comes from the PHP code

Comment: How do you manage to use in PHP in Highcharts?

Comment: https://codepen.io/WhoAmIAmWho/pen/vQdwjP Just click on download pdf and in the pdf document you can see the text ("Test Case"). In this place I want to use the PHP code to display text/numbers

Comment: And how do you call the PHP?

Comment: Just like in the link posted in main topic along with the code.

Comment: You have an additional </text> in there, right before text.

Comment: You cannot add php code to a seperate js file. You would have to have the js inline, as the php will only run server side. I trust that is the case?

Comment: it's returning me "Failed to get SVG" (If PHP outputs text)

Comment: Again, how do you get that PHP? Is it a file on your local hard disc that you import? Or is it a script on a server which output you include somehow into your script?

Comment: it's a script on a server

Comment: And does this script work correctly and returns some proper, valid SVG?

Comment: I got it. There's a bit of syntax error in the PHP statement and I corrected it. Thanks a lot for your help in finding out the issue